# Representing json return format as different format

Tags: java, json

I made a method in rest service and tested it in postman and it returns this format:

```
{
    "account": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "password": "a",
            "pop3": "pop3",
            "smtp": "smtp",
            "username": "a"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code of my service method:

```
@GET
@Path("/accounts")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Account> getAccounts(){

        Account a = new Account();
        a.setId(1);
        a.setSmtp("smtp");
        a.setPop3("pop3");
        a.setUsername("a");
        a.setPassword("a");

        List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
        accounts.add(a);
        return accounts;
}
```

**Is there a way to return in this format?**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "password": "a",
        "pop3": "pop3",
        "smtp": "smtp",
        "username": "a"
    }
]
```

Comment: You added the account to the account list. How do you expect it to return anything but a list of accounts?

Comment: I want to return list of accounts but without this part "account":

Comment: No it isn’t. What you want is not a valid json

Comment: What Jens said. What's the problem with using it the way it is naturally returned?